# How to create sum in Numbers up to a specific row?

Tags: numbers

I have column which contains prices for my work. The last row of that column should contain the total. Currently I have to adjust the `SUM()` calculation every time I add or remove a row. 
Can I somehow magically sum up to the row the `SUM()` formula is contained in?

Comment: What exactly is the formula for sum? Do you care about steps for iOS numbers, OS X numbers or all versions?

Comment: How do you add and remove rows?

Comment: Numbers on OS X. Actually, Numbers inside of Pages. I simply presumed that this is the same "control".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this using header and footer rows. These automatically adjust the formulas contained within them based on the number of rows above.

1. Make sure you have the footer row enabled:

   [image]
2. In the footer cell, enter =SUM↩︎.
3. Select the column by clicking the relevant header cell or column reference.

The formula will automatically adjust from now on.

---

An animation for further explanation:

[image: GIF]

Comment: Note that that <Enter> keypress after typing sum is critical. Without it, this weirdly doesn't work.